# MVC - html.dropdownlist - calling javascript or controller/method directly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

In my MVC application, I have a html.dropdownlist in my view. On selection changed - I want the value to be passed on to a method (that returns something like a list or a JsonResult) in the controller.

Q1: How do I do this?

```
 <%=Html.DropDownList("title", Model.Titleitems, "" )%>
```

Q2: Is this a good practice (having controller/method name in the view directly) or should I write a JavaScript function and call the appropriate controller/method from inside that JavaScript function? In that case, how can I write a Onchange or OnSelectionChanged event for the above html.dropdownlist control?

EDIT:

par1 is the dropdownlist selected value I want to pass to this controller/method..

```
       public ActionResult GetMethod(string Par1)
        {
            //My code here 

            return Json(varValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
```

Now I have the dropdownlist on change taking me to a JavaScript function (as per marteljn suggestion) and in the JavaScript function, I have .ajax call specifying URL and type etc. that takes me to the controller/method code; but still not able to figure out how to pass the selected value to the controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q2 is the answer to Q1. There are no events when using MVC like there are in web forms, so you will write some JavaScript to make a request back to the server.
There are (at least) two ways to go about it:

1. Inline Event Handler (not recommended)

   `<%=Html.DropDownList("title", Model.Titleitems, new{@onchange = "YourJsFuncHere()"} )%>`
2. The JQuery way,

   ```
   $("#title").bind("change",function(){
        //Your Code  
        //Use .on instead of bind if you are using JQuery 1.7.x or higher   
        //http://api.jquery.com/on/ 
   });
   ```

**Edit - The AJAX Code**

```
$.ajax({
  "url": "/Controller/Action/" + $("#title").val(),
  "type": "get",
  "dataType" : "json",
  "success": function(data){
    //Your code here
    //data should be your json result
  }
});
```

Change `GetMethod(string Par1)` to `GetMethod(string id)` or change your default route to reflect the `Par1` parameter.

Also, if its not hitting your break point its possible that 1) the AJAX request is not being initied (use firebug to see if it is) 2) Your routes are not configured properly (Look  in Global.asax.cs, if you haven't moved the routing somewhere else.

Comment: So where does the controller/method come into picture if I am using the Jquery way? Because I have code in the controller method that takes in the drop down selected value and runs some logic..

Comment: You can either 1) Make an AJAX request in your JavaScript function to the controller like `$.ajax({url : "/Controller/Action"...` 2) do `location.href = "/Controller/Action";` which will send you to that page.  Based on your question I think approach 1) is what you want to do.

Comment: I tried 1).. but break point in the controller does not hit at all.I checked the javascript itself runs well (using alerts).. Here is the code so far.. $.ajax({
        
        url: '/ControllerA/MethodA',
    }); and also how do I pass the drop down list value to the controller action method which is expecting parameters

Comment: changed the method to public from private- that fixed the breakpoint issue.. sorry dont know how that got in there.

Comment: What exactly goes into the function(data) code.. for my case, all I need is to pass the selected value to the controller/method.. I think you are already doing that before getting to that function(data) line of code..

Comment: My Controller Method code is like this...    public ActionResult GetMethod(string Par1)
        {
            //My code here... 
            return Json(var, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        } how do I get Par1 value from the drop down list passed into this method in the controller is basically my question..

Comment: Please see OP for new EDITs. Thank you.

Comment: I made an edit, remove the `data` and append your value to the URL.  You need to make sure your routing is configured in the Global.asax.cs file to handle the arguement you are passing.  If you don't understand what I am saying, post the contents of the Global.asax.cs file and I'll point you to what change needs to be made.

Comment: Appending the value to the URL - does it get complicated if I have to pass more than one value to the method in controller...

Comment: Yes, the but it is not that bad.  You need to configure your route to handle the params passed.  If you post the what is currently configured and what you want to do, I can show you exactly how to configure it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  $("#title").change(function(){
   var selectedVal=$(this).val();
   $.getJSON("UserController/YourAction",{ id: selectedVal} , function(result ){
       //Now you can access the jSon data here in the result variable
   });

 });

});
```

Assuming you have an Action method called `YourAction` in your `UserController` which returns JSON

```
public ActionResult YourAction(int id)
{
  //TO DO : get data from wherever you want. 

   var result=new { Success="True", Message="Some Info"};
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

}
```